# Align paths not in respect to horizontals or verticals but angled lines in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, alignment

I want to align two paths in illustrator which are tilted (I indicated the desired alignment with a grey dashed line). Alignment only works according to horizontals and verticals, but not in respect to the tilt-angle of lines themselves.
Is there a smart way to do this?

Goal
[image: Goal]

Comment: The alignment tools are for vertical and horizontal alignment only. To make 2 angled lines parallel I duplicate 1 line and offset it, or rotate the whole thing so the lines are horizontal or vertical, then do the aligning, then rotate it back.

Comment: Thank you Webster. And how do you set precise distances (again along the angled plane not in horizontal or vertical)? I hoped to avoid dozens of pythagorean theorem calculations.

Comment: Hi Soli, if you copy and "paste in place" your line you can then shift it precisely with  Object>Transform>Move, then enter the number of pixels and direction. For short distances I also count number of taps with the arrow keys (I have it set to 1 pixel 1 tap)